# Mapping Using New Array() Syntax

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary

So I noticed today that if you create an Array using the non-usual `new Array(<array_length>)` syntax, you will be unable to map over the values correctly.

A simple example:

```
var newArr = new Array(10);

newArr = newArr.map(function(val) {
  alert("It's really happening!");
  return 200;
});


console.log(newArr);
```

The result after running is still an empty array, nor does any of the `alert`'s fire off.

Any ideas why the `new Array()`s passed in `.map()` function doesn't work in this example?

Comment: Because `.map` ignores "holes". See http://es5.github.io/#x15.4.4.19

Comment: @FelixKling If I do `[undefined,undefined,undefined.map()` the methods will fire.  I guess this works because it still technically has the values there?

Comment: Yes, in every possible sense the array has three elements (each of them is the value `undefined`)) (`console.dir([undefined,undefined,undefined])`). That's not the case with `Array(x)` (`console.dir(Array(3))`). The latter basically just sets `length` to `3`.

Comment: Put differently, we are talking about the difference between `({0: undefined}[0])` and `({}[0])`. The first one returns `undefined` because the value of the property `0` is `undefined`. The second one is `undefined` because accessing a non-existing property returns `undefined`. The second has the "hole".

Comment: @FelixKling Ahh, that makes sense.

Also bonus points to the downvoters, appreciate it.

Comment: String(Array(10)).split(",")